# python scrapy check if the class exists else check for other

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to using Scrapy. My response will have this structure.

```
<div class="padb-property-card">
<div class="padb-listing-id">
    <span>Listing ID: </span>777247      </div>
<div class='padb-ribbon padb-ribbon-not-sold'><span>Not sold</span></div>
</div>
<div class="padb-property-card">
<div class="padb-listing-id">
    <span>Listing ID: </span>777248      </div>
<div class='padb-ribbon padb-ribbon-sold-post'><span>Sold Post</span></div>
</div>
<div class="padb-property-card">
<div class="padb-listing-id">
    <span>Listing ID: </span>777249      </div>
<div class='padb-ribbon padb-ribbon-sold'><span>Sold</span></div>
</div>
```

I can use this

```
response.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'padb-ribbon') and contains(@class, 'padb-ribbon-sold')]").extract()
```

for finding sold results, but the classes differ based on the property auction results. There are three different class types `padb-ribbon-not-sold`, `padb-ribbon-sold-post`, `padb-ribbon-sold`. How do i capture this in order?

Comment: It's not clear why do you need that. Do you want to get Listing IDs for the `Sold` status? Or do you want to get status for each Listing ID?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘How do i capture this in order?’?. Can you show how your current code does it ‘not in order’?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I need to capture the sold status for each listing Id.

Comment: Kindly provide your code to analyze what should be done to achieve the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following xpath to get the sold status for each listing:

```
sold_status = response.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class,"padb-ribbon")]/span/text()').extract_first()
```

Not sure what the page structure looks like, but if you need to loop through the property-cards you can do something like this:

```
property_xpaths = response.xpath('//*[@class="padb-property-card"]/div')
for property_xpath in property_xpaths:
    sold_status = property_xpath.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class,"padb-ribbon")]/span/text()').extract_first()
```